# Node.js http requests much slower than browser or .NET

Tags: node.js, performance, http, request

I'm using the latest Node.js v8.9.3 to make requests to a RESTful API and I'm getting very disappointing results in terms of performance.

The best results I get are ~800ms using node, while it takes around ~300ms for the same request to complete from the browser, using curl or a simple two lines request from C#.

I've tried both native http and https modules for requests, and also some other libraries (req-fast, node-fetch, even emulated XMLHttpRequest) to no avail, these other options are even slower.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there anything that can be done differently, or we just have to assume the node wrapper is slower no matter what?

Sample code that I'm using:

```
var start = new Date();
var options = {
  host: 'www.binance.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=ETHBTC',
  method: 'GET',
};
https.get(options, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
    var end = new Date() - start;
    console.info("Execution time: %dms", end);
  });

}).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
});
```

Result: ~830ms

Results from Chrome:
[chrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdPI5.jpg)

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about, I have even written DDOS tools with this library, and it is really fast. Have you tried sending a `request` to another domain? Or with a faster connection? Maybe it's the API problem or soemthing but then why is it fast in C# is scrapping my mind..

Comment: Please use the `var start = new Date();` within **https.get** otherwise start value will be consider as time even before the code started execution. I tried and it was **5ms** -- Give it a try

Comment: @turmuka Yes, I tried from an Azure instance, from an France based VPS and from my office with similar results. Oddly enough, other APIs are not that far appart in result times. I wonder what's different about Binance's endpoint.

Comment: @nagaraja-malla To me, this is the time that is important. Even if the request itself is faster, this is the effective time it takes for me to get the response back so that I can use it in my following code. It's not important if it's because of processing time (bad) or the network connection (which should be identical to other methods).

Comment: I think, I have a similar problem.  I test my code with ab. Something like:

`ab -n 1000 -c 100 http://localhost:8081/api/http`

But the last 10 or 20 requests always take so much time... Some times (not always ) I get the folllowing exception:

socket hang up at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:331:15....